# Paste clipboard content (table) to HTML body

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, thunderbird

I need to copy a table content into an e-mail. The used mail-client is Thunderbird.

I did a lot of research and found out that it is impossible to paste a table into Thunderbird, just pasting it as plain text is working. 
There should be a workarround: 1. pasting the table to Word 2. copying it and pasting it into the HTML body.

Unfortunately, I got stuck on that. How can I paste the clipboard content to the HTML body?

I tried 2 different ways.

```
Sub ExcelToTB()
Dim rangeToCopy As Range
Dim WordApp As Object
Dim objTable As Table
Dim objSourceDoc As Object

Set rangeToCopy = Sheets(2).Range("A1:J150")

Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = True

Set objSourceDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add



rangeToCopy.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

objSourceDoc.Words(1).PasteExcelTable False, False, False

WordApp.Activate

ActiveDocument.Table(1).Select
```

Here it states that no document is activated in the last line, although the App got activated in the line before.

So my second attempt was:

```
Dim rangeToCopy As Range
Dim WordApp As Object
Dim objTable As Table
Dim objSourceDoc As Object

Set rangeToCopy = Sheets(2).Range("A1:J150")

Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = True

Set objSourceDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add



rangeToCopy.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

objSourceDoc.Words(1).PasteExcelTable False, False, False

For Each objTable In objSourceDoc.Tables
    objTable.Range.Copy
Next objTable


Dim TBstart As String

TBstart = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe" & _
                " -compose format=1,preselectid=id1" & _
                ",to='test@test.com',subject='Test'" & _
                ",body='This is just a test'"
Shell TBstart, 3

End Sub
```

With the second attempt, the table is stored to the clipboard an I can paste it manually. But how can I implement it into the body?

I tried:

```
TBstart = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe" & _
                " -compose format=1,preselectid=id1" & _
                ",to='test@test.de',subject='Test'" & _
                ",body='Dies ist eine Testmail'" & objTable
```

...but then it states that the types are incompatible.

Does maybe anyone of you have an idea how to solve it? I am testing it since 3 days without any success :-(

Comment: In the first method, change `.Table(1)` to `.Tables(1)` Also instead of `ActiveDocument` you can use `objSourceDoc.Tables(1).select`

Comment: Also see if [THIS](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15316/Excel-to-HTML-Macro) helps? I have not tested it...

Comment: Dear Siddharth Rout
I tried your first suggestion as well, but then it does not select the table. I used a msgBox to show me the indexnumber of the table. It was 1. But it never selects the table. Thank you so far, also for your link :-)

Comment: Have you tried RangeToHtml by Ron De Bruin?

Comment: `objSourceDoc.Tables(1).select` does select the table. I tried it again :)